# Working out operation counts for matrix-vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, floating-point

I'm working on a problem about the multiplication of a matrix $A$ of order $m \times n$ by a vector $b$. In particular I'm supposed to determine the number of operations needed.

What is the point of this though? It really gives me more motivation and helps me understand when I understand WHY I am doing something.

Isn't this just showing me how badly my algorithm is messing up calculations? How am I supposed to add these sums for any number of calculations I do?

Comment: What are "Flop counts"?

Comment: @coffeemath:  counting the number of floating point operations.  In the ancient days they were far slower than integer operations and could dominate the time needed for a program to run.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the definition. Also this may answer OP's query about the point of counting them.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to estimate how long an algorithm will take and how it scales with the size of the input.  In your example of a matrix multiply you have $mn$ entries in A.  Each one has to get multiplied by an entry in b, so there are $mn$ multiplies.  Then you have to do $(m-1)n$ additions to get the entries in the result.  We can ignore the $-1$ and say the effort expended is $2mn$ floating point operations.  If you can do a billion operations in a reasonable amount of time you can afford to have $m$ and $n$ be tens of thousands but not millions.

Some operations have alternate algorithms with different timing.  Sorting is a prime example.  Some simple minded sorting algorithms scale as the square of the number of items sorted, so again you could afford to sort a few tens of thousands of things but not millions.  There are other algorithms that work in $n \log n$ time.  Now you can afford to sort tens of millions.  That is an enormous increase.

Comment: Shouldn't the flop count for this be O(n^2)?

Comment: There are $mn$ entries in $A$ and each one gets multiplied by one entry in $b$, so there are $mn$ multiplies.  That is $n^2$ if $A$ is square, but you did not specify that.